# Search only a specific field in ui.bootstrap typeahead

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm refining my ui.bootstrap typeahead adding some awesomness, but I'm struggling on this one.

I've created a small Plunker to demonstrate my issue:
http://plnkr.co/edit/u2Le37?p=preview

**Two words about the issue:**
I have this array of objects which populate my `$scope.data` but I'm not able to tell `typeahead` to use only a particular field to search the result

```
$scope.data = [
  {
    name: 'Mario',
    desc: 'Super Plumber',
    id: 0,
    type: 'good'
  },
  {
    name: 'Luigi',
    desc: 'Assistant Plumber',
    id: 1,
    type: 'good'
  }, 
...
```

Whenever you search in the typeahead, you'll search for every field in the object, even `type` and `id`

I've tried, without success, solution like these:

```
typeahead="datum.name as ( datum.name +', '+ datum.desc) 
    for datum in data | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8"

---> no change


typeahead="datum as ( datum.name +', '+ datum.desc) 
    for datum.name in data | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8"

--> no match
```

How can I restrict the search to, let's say, the `name` field?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The magical line is as following

```
filter:{name: $viewValue}
```

This would limit the search to only name field. Look at this document ion for [ng-filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter)

> **Object**: A pattern object can be used to filter specific properties on
>   objects contained by array. For example *{name:"M", phone:"1"}*
>   predicate will return an array of items which have property name
>   containing "M" and property phone containing "1". A special property
>   name *$* can be used (as in *{$:"text"}*) to accept a match against any
>   property of the object. That's equivalent to the simple substring
>   match with a string as described above.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RQAUzNnZcrMaZbgAotwL?p=preview) Updated

Comment: Exactly! This is the awesome part of the typeahead - it simply builds on top of the existing AngularJS infrastructure!

Comment: Awesome!  Simply as that. Thx very much guys

Comment: Ok, great, the filter it's great with one field, but with multiple filters (Which seems supported as stated in the doc) it behaves very weirdly.
Please take a look at this new Plunker --> http://plnkr.co/edit/3eTeE31b5aXX7j0EAT33?p=preview

Comment: @domokun - where you able to get the typeahead working with multiple filters?

Comment: Hey @parsh it's been quite a while, but I remember that I had to develop my own filter to make it work on multiple elements.
If you don't find any answer on SO, ask a new question (and give me the link, or @me) and I will attach my response there, so it will remain visible for everyone for any further needs.

Comment: @parsh EDIT: I've checked the code, and my custom filter was totally unrelated (limit the number of items to view based on a category)...